# AIX Command to get LPAR entitlement usage

Tags: command-line, cpu-usage, aix

I would like to know with a command what is the entitlement usage in my LPARs.

I have thought to the topas command: save information in a file and send it to datawarehouse.

```
topasrec -L -c 5 -s 60
```

But when try to read the content file, it is in binary.

**Workaround**:

I have changed the approach to the problem. 
I could not catch whole text with ssh streaming because I receive only changed chars.
Hence periodically I run the following ssh command to save nmon content in a file (called *hostname_YYMMDD_H24_mm.nmon*):

```
nmon -f -c 1
```

After with the cat command I can read the file, extract the content, transform it and load it in my dashboard.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `lparstat -i` ?

Comment: @C0deDaedalus - I have just tried: it shows the entitled capacity, but it doesn't seem to show the capacity usage at the moment. I would like know how much use of that.

Comment: Topas or nmon commands show lpar realtime statistics but I cannot capture those with a script.